# WordPress max upload size error on XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp

When I try to upload a theme that is roughly 2.3MB when zipped, I get this error message:

*The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.*

In order to remedy this, I have modified the php.ini file in the wp-admin folder to specify:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Yet, it still does not work. I have tried restarting my XAMPP server and clearing my cache but it still gives me the same error message. I have also tried placing a file called "php5.ini" with the same contents as the "php.ini" file in the same wp-admin folder--still nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have modified the php.ini file in the wp-admin folder

This does not sound right. The parameters your setting are all fine, but if you're using Windows, the location of the php.ini file should be:

xampp\php\php.ini

On Mac, it should be:

private/etc/php.ini

Just make sure you edit the php.ini file at the right location, then save and restart the httpd service (or reboot) when done and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem but editing my php.ini file with similar configurations did not work.
What worked for me was adding the following lines to my .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 400M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```